# find unused and duplicate indexes in in-memory OLTP database

Tags: in-memory-database

I have a SQL Server 2016 in-memory OLTP database. I want to know how can I get the list of unused & duplicate hash index & non-clustered indexes there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query that maintains stats about your memory-optimized indexes: -

```
SELECT ix.index_id, ix.name, scans_started, rows_returned 
    FROM sys.dm_db_xtp_index_stats ixs JOIN sys.indexes ix ON ix.object_id=ixs.object_id AND ix.index_id=ixs.index_id 
    WHERE ix.object_id=object_id('**<table_name>**')
```

The rows_returned and scans_started are good indicators. More info here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-xtp-index-stats-transact-sql